# Irreps of $S_3=GL(2,2)$. Who is cuspidal?

Tags: representation-theory

$S_3 = GL(2, F_2)$. It has $3$ irreps - trivial, sign, standard 2d.

Can one help me to understand general words about Irreps of $G(F_q)$ ("principal series", "parabolically induced", "cuspidal", "complimentrary series", "Steinberg irrep") in this particular example ?
I mean who of these irreps is who ?

Notes on the subject I am looking:

Paul Garrett: http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/toy_GL2.pdf

Etingof&Students: http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0827

Amritanshu Prasad http://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/html_notes/notes.html#notesch2.html

Comment: Side remark: Have a look at Weintraub - "Representation theory of finite group" in the section Mackey Machine http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38571/classifying-the-irreducible-representations-of-mathbbz-p-mathbbz-rtimes-m/38589#38589  What is the relationship between Mackey's theorem in character theory and Mackey's theorem in transfer theory?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189430/what-is-the-relationship-between-mackeys-theorem-in-character-theory-and-mackey?rq=1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153381/estimates-on-conjugacy-classes-of-a-finite-group Estimates on conjugacy classes of a finite group. Theorem:
Let A be a normal subgroup of G such that A is the centralizer of every non-trivial element in A. If further G/A is abelian, then G has |G:A| linear characters, and (|A|−1)/|G:A| non-linear irreducible characters of degree =|G:A| which vanish off A. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117500/conjugacy-classes-of-the-nonabelian-group-of-order-21

Comment: Let  be a normal subgroup of a finite group . Let  belonging to  be a conjugacy class of elements in , and assume that  belongs to . Prove that  is a union of  conjugacy classes in , all having the same cardinality, where  equals the index  of the group generated by  and the centralizer  in  of and element  belonging to . http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/a-question-about-group-decomposition-of-conjugacy-classes-in-normal-subgroups?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the "parabolically-induced" (="principal series") repn's standard model is just left $P$-invariant ($P$=upper-triangular) functions on the group $G$, since there is only the trivial character on diagonal things $M=\{1\}$. This repn is $|G|/|P|$-dimensional, that is, $(3\cdot 2)/2=3$, contains the trivial repn, obviously, and the 2-dimensional complement is the "Steinberg", by conventional naming. Evidently, the single "supercuspidal" (meaning sums to $0$ over the unipotent radical $N$ of $P$) is the "sign" repn. A peculiar outcome!